# JavaScript onclick event for button/function elemtn_onclick() difference

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I have question about the difference between the following code. Which method is more preferable? Why? Pro's/Con's?

More of a better question: What other events are there other than onclick? What about on change events?

**Method 1**

```
HtmlId.onclick = function () {

alert("whatever");

}
```

**Method 2**

```
function HtmlId_onclick() {

 alert("whatever");

}
```

The reason why I"m curious is that method # 1 didn't work so I just double-clicked the button in visual studio and it added the function automatically which worked. So why do things the manual way when that is automatic?

Comment: Visual studio will automatically generate nasty code that is buggy cross-browser and doesn't scale well. The reason to do things the manual way is because you will know what's happening rather than relying on a tool performing "magic" for you.

Comment: That makes sense. So why would method 1 not work and method 2 work? (I'm in IE 10)

Comment: It looks like you're using ASP.NET, which means that any server control will have an automatically generated ID attribute to enforce uniqueness. What this means is that `HtmlId` will not be the appropriate ID of the element, instead you will find that the ID will be along the lines of `ParentControl_0_AncestorControl_3_HtmlId`. Typically you're better off using a class or `[data-*]` attribute selector to select an element before binding events. Your example in method 1 doesn't account for the possibility that the ID is not a valid JavaScript identifier, or has been overwritten globally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method #2 is the better way of writing functions, You should always a try to write it manually, especially with visual studios. It can sometimes add really odd code or misinterpret the issue or just put in wrong variables and stuff and then you're left with an issue and no idea how to fix it.